In England, can I break a contract if the framework agreement it relies on is potentially void?
I've entered into a deal that's turned out to be commercially unfavourable for me, and I'm looking to break it off. There are two contracts involved: the first is a general framework agreement about supplying and purchasing goods, while the second is more specific about the conditions of sale.
There's a clause in the second agreement that says something like "this agreement is made subject to the initial agreement (i.e. the first agreement)".
I've recently looked into the timeline more closely and discovered that the first agreement was signed after the consideration was provided. This might mean the first agreement is void (or was never properly entered into).
Are there any arguments I could make to say that because the first agreement is void or non-existent, the second agreement isn't enforceable (or is void) as well?
I know the chances of breaking off the deal are slim, as there might be a severability clause. But I'm wondering if there are any arguments I could use to make the second agreement unenforceable. Would interpretation/construction or implied terms be relevant here?
Thanks a lot!!

The first agreement is not void
It is common for contracts to not be formally signed (if they ever are) after one party or the other has provided some or all of the consideration. A contract is entered when the agreement is reached (often by the acceptance of an offer), not when a document is signed.
It is extremely difficult verging on impossible for a contract that both parties have acted as though it existed to be declared void. It’s clear from their actions that there was a contract, there might be dispute about particular terms but saying there wasn’t one at all will be rightly viewed as disingenuous.
Forget implied terms
Unless there is a statute that implies them, or a long-standing common law precedent (e.g. that goods will be merchantable and fit for purpose), implied terms are virtually impossible to prove. To be implied a term must be:

Necessary to make the contract work (i.e. if there is a reading of the contract that works without the implied term, it isn’t needed),
So obvious it “goes without saying”, which means that of all possible terms needed to fix the contract, this is clearly the only one that anyone would agree to.

Suck it up or break the contract
You are allowed to break a contract and pay damages. Depending on the situation, damages may cost you less than complying with the terms. That’s a commercial decision, not a legal one.

Thanks a lot. I was thinking like if the 1st agreement was signed after the consideration had been provided then because it is past consideration, the contract would be void...

@MarkYoo that's lunacy. I can give you a 20 dollar bill with a verbal loan and then we sign a contract that sets conditions and such for repayment and that later contract just absorbs the verbal agreement
